# Enabling fish-style manpage-based completion in bash

Tags: bash, fish

One of the really appealing features of fish is that it supports intelligent tab completion of options based on their specifications in each command's respective manpage. Has anyone created a way to enable bash's tab-completion intelligence with this data?

Answer (score 2):

If you are refering to whether the option value is completed given the option indicator is already typed, `bash` indeed does have that functionality (see e.g. the [documentation on programmable completion](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html)). It can not, as far as I know, be automatically generated from the manpage, however.

The [`sh-manpage-completions` project](https://github.com/nevesnunes/sh-manpage-completions) goes in that direction, and it seems to be based on `fish`s (python-based) mechanism.